# Displaying the total price of the Items of my Offer in a template

Tags: python, django

I've got two Models: `Offer and Items`. My Offer always has an variable amount of Items, which have a price. Now I'd like to display the total sum of the price of the items for each Offer.

How can I do that?

These are my Models:

```
class Offer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(default="", verbose_name='Offername', blank=False, max_length=255)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=django_now, verbose_name='Date')
    number = models.TextField(default="", verbose_name='Offernumber', blank=True)

class Item(models.Model):
        number = models.CharField('Nr.', blank=False, default="", max_length=10)
        description = models.TextField(default="", blank=False, verbose_name='Beschreibung')
        costs = models.DecimalField('Price', blank=False, default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
        offer = models.ForeignKey('Offer', null=True, verbose_name="Angebot", related_name="items", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

What I'm trying to do is showing the total sum of all ITEMS that belong to one OFFER. So lets say I've got 2 Offers, each has a DetailView and inside this DetailView I display the Items for every offer. Offer 1 has 3 Items and Offer 2 has 9 Items. Now I want to display for Offer 1 the sum of the 3 items and for Offer 2 the total sum of his 9 items and so on.

**Edit:** My view

```
class OfferDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Offer
    template_name = 'offers/offer_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'offer'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**

You will have to override the `DetailView` behaviour for this:

```
class OfferDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Offer
    template_name = 'offers/offer_detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'offer'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        offer = self.object
        total_item_cost = sum([i.cost for i in offer.item])
        context['total_item_cost'] = total_item_cost
        return context
```

and in the template : `{{ total_item_cost }}`

(see [this part of the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_context_data))

**Initial answer**

I think the simplest way is to use [django annotation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/) to perform the sum at database level. Also see [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards) for your case.

Something like this might work (not tested):

```
from django.db.models import Sum
offers = Offer.objects.all().annotate(total_costs=Sum("item__costs"))
```

and in template you can now use:

```
{% for offer in offers %}
 {{ offer.total_costs  }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think there was a little misunderstanding. If I'm not wrong  what you are doing is getting all Offers and then get the total Sum? But what I'm trying to do is showing the total sum of all ITEMS that belong to one OFFER. So I've got like 3 Offers, each has a DetailView and inside this DetailView I display the Items for every offer, like lets say Offer 1 has 3 Items and Offer 2 has 9 Items. And now I want for Offer 2 to display the sum of the 3 items and for Offer 2 the total sum of 9 items and so on. Sorry for the misunderstanding!

Comment: The annotation is computing the total sum of item for each offer, if you can get it for all offer, you might be able to make the changes to get only one offer. But for a single offer, there might be simpler approach. Can you show your view ?

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the answer accordingly. The idea is to slightly modify the DetailView behaviour to add the information you need to the context, and then you can access this information directly in the template.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked, I just had to do a small modification, instead of `(..)for i in offer.item]` I did `(..)for i in Item.objects.filter(offer=offer.pk)]` as my Offer Model does not has an item field, but my item has an offer field :)

Comment: `ForeignKey` relation can be used in both direction. Maybe the filed in Offer is `item_set` and not `item`. Anyway, good that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can do something like this should  work in your case.

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def get_total_item_offer(self):
    total_items = Offer.objects.all()
    return self.get_total_item.total_items.all().aggregate(sum=Sum('total')['sum']
```

Answer (score 0):

Django annotation will work. In your offer model add

```
 def get_total_price(self):
     return self.objects.annotate(total_price_sum=Sum("item__costs"))
```

Each offer model now has a field called total_price_sum which contains the total price of each model associated with it